# Flutter: A value of type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code to display `DatePicker` and after which `TimePicker` will come up and I will retrive all the seleted values and it was working perfectly fine until I migrated to null safety by creating a flutter project and coping all my code to the new project and also and doing a few "pub get, Upgrade"

Below is my code:

```
  //Select Date and Time Widget
  Future _selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime _selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => child);

    TimeOfDay _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (_selectedDay != null && _selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedDateAndTime = DateTime(
        _selectedDay.year,
        _selectedDay.month,
        _selectedDay.day,
        _selectedTime.hour,
        _selectedTime.minute,
      );
      // _selectedDate = _selectedDay;
    });
    // print('...');
  }
```

Now I got this error:

> A value of type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'DateTime'.
>
> A value of type 'TimeOfDay?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'TimeOfDay'.

Check the image to see... I have gone through the questions I saw on almost same issue but it did not solve my problem

[image]

[image]

How do i solve this error

Answer (score 4):

[showDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) returns Future `DateTime?`:

```
Future<DateTime?> showDatePicker(...)
```

So, you need to change the following:

```
DateTime _selectedDay = await showDatePicker(...)
```

to:

```
DateTime? _selectedDay = await showDatePicker(...)
```

[showTimePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showTimePicker.html) returns Future `TimeOfDay?`:

```
Future<TimeOfDay?> showTimePicker(...)
```

So, change the following:

```
TimeOfDay _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(...);
```

to:

```
TimeOfDay? _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(...);
```

Comment: That's work. And how to add validation?

Answer (score 0):

Either null safe variable like `TimeOfDay?`, or you can get the value at risk with `(await showTimePicker(...))!`

[Check more for null safety of dart](https://dart.dev/null-safety)